# I would like to enrich myself talking about pseudo code in now a days, where i should go?

Tags: discussion

Could someone know where to go and chat about that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly what do you want to ask about pseudocode?

If you want to ask specific questions about algorithms and data structures, those are on-topic here. We consider those as software design questions. However, you should know that we are most interested in building robust and high quality software. Intense mathematical or scientific discussion of algorithms and data structures would be more suited to Computer Science.

If you want to ask specific questions about how to fit pseudocoding into your design process, that's on-topic here. We deal with design and methodology questions.

If you want someone to help debug your pseudocode and make sure it's right, you should probably turn it into your programming language and use a debugger and test tools. If you can't get it, then you can go to Stack Overflow.

If you just want to chat, why not....[come to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard)?

Comment: Thanks for your time Thomas... i would like only to collect personal opinions about the importance (or not) of the pseudo code learning trait in a person that aim to be a software developer. Probably it will fit in the chat! Thanks again for you answer! Soon i will go there!